# Impossible to store certain datetime formats in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

At the moment I have a column that holds timestamps as a `datetime`

The data is being stored as `10/30/2011 10:50:34 AM`

My goal is to convert every date in that specific table to be formatted like `30 Oct 2011 10:50:34`

The problem:

When I attempt to run this SQL it successfully processes.

```
UPDATE DatesTable 
SET DateTime = '30 Oct 2011 10:50:34' 
WHERE DateTime = '10/30/2011 10:50:34 AM'
```

I noticed that was weird so if I changed the SQL to say

```
UPDATE DatesTable 
SET DateTime = '31 Oct 2011 10:50:34' 
WHERE DateTime = '10/30/2011 10:50:34 AM'
```

It updates updates the datetime field with the correct day/time information but keeps it in the same format.

I have looked into other possible date datatypes for that column but nothing seems to support that date.
I have also come across this SQL but am unsure if it can solve my problem.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, datecolumnname, formattingparam) as tmp FROM tablename
```

[Converting Link](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't store a `DateTime` in any string format - it's stored as an 8 byte numerical value.

The various settings (language, date format) only influence how the `DateTime` is shown to you in SQL Server Management Studio - or how it is parsed when you attempt to convert a string to a `DateTime`.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion) - note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

The data is stored independent of format. You only need to reformat dates for display purposes.

Answer (score 2):

sql server doesn't store the data in a text format.  It is stored as a number.

Check out this page for how to format dates in sql 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `datetime` datatype tells the database engine how to store the data internally, so that you don't need to worry about human representations of the data. This is why your different `UPDATE` scripts don't change the format. The format is only applied when converting from the database's internal storage (a number representing the amount of time passed since a particular starting-point) and a human-readable date in the culture you require. You just need to format the date when it gets displayed, in the format suitable for your users. For example, for many, Month/Day/Year makes no sense.