# Comparing dates with current date in Sql server

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table which has list of some events with dates. I am trying to write a stored procedure that will return only the upcoming events.

I have written the following query in the stored procedure:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       Events
WHERE      tDate >= (select CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
```

But this is not returning correct result. This is also showing results that have dates less than current date. How to write a query that will return all the events that have date equal or greater than today's date.

Edit: Dates that have been entered on the table have the format yyyy/dd/mm and getdate() returns date in the format yyyy/mm/dd. I think this is causing the problem. Dates that have been entered into the table has been taken using jquery date picker. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: "...greater than today's date" - use "greater than" (>) instead of "greater than or equal" (>=)

Comment: What's wrong with simply `WHERE tDate > GETDATE()`?

Comment: the question isn't immediately clear on that, but i suppose the time part?

Comment: can you provide example of result of this query and the excepted output

Comment: @ughai this query returning results with dates 2015-09-04, 2015-10-04. But results should have with dates equal or greater than 2015-14-04

Comment: @uttam - what is the datatype of tDate. DATE? or CHAR? I think when you are passing the string value you need to specify the correct format from jquery date picker

Comment: @ughai data type is Date

Comment: check this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04d9917d-fc05-4e3e-ba70-0e8a3eac3fe8/sql-server-incorrectly-parsing-dates-as-yyyyddmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `DATE` data is incorrectly stored within Sql Server. When your application passes the string `'2015-09-04'` and you save that your date column, it is saved as 4th Sept 2015 and not 9th April 2015. Hence your query returns such rows as they are greater than `GETDATE()`.

**Example**

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(10) = '2015-09-04'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(DATE,@D),109)
```

you need to fix your data and then use a `CONVERT` with style when saving dates in your table from application, using something like this. `CONVERT(DATE, '20150409',112)`

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(10) = '20150409'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(DATE,@D,112),109)
```

Refer these threads for more info:

[Impossible to store certain datetime formats in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362198/impossible-to-store-certain-datetime-formats-in-sql-server)

[Cast and Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you have an additional select

```
SELECT     *
FROM       Events
WHERE      tDate >= CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
```